# Unable to install Windows after installing openSUSE and Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, bootloader, opensuse

I had a Windows machine then I decided to try openSUSE so I burned into a USB and I was presented with a long list of partitions and stuff. I deleted EVERYTHING and it seems I messed up the bootloader.

When I insert a valid Windows USB to remove everything and go back to Windows again it's not being detected.

However, when I insert Ubuntu USB it's detected and I can install it. In fact I now completely removed openSUSE and I have Ubuntu because it's the only thing that worked for me.

What can I do now to get Windows only on my machine? If I hit esc when booting I am redirected to GRUB but not sure what to do now. All I want to the machine detecting my Windows 8.1 USB to remove everything and install it.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know it's a valid bootable Windows USB installation media?  Have you tried it on any other PCs?  How did you create it?

From the sound of it, the PC is configured to boot off USB properly, which means that if it's getting to the GRUB screen, it hasn't detected any bootable USB sticks.  So it goes to the hard drive, which starts GRUB.

You can try using the [Windows USB Download Tool](http://wudt.codeplex.com) to create the USB media.

Comment: I know because I fully installed it on a different machine that had Ubuntu. And I created it using Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool.

Comment: So when you try to boot it, it skips it entirely?  It doesn't come up with any "Boot image not found" type messages?

Does your BIOS give you the option to specify a boot source?  If so, does it do anything different if you tell it to go straight to USB?